# Sending Automated SMS in React Native

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

Im am trying to send an automated SMS message with an OTP code in it to the user when they click on a button in their react native app. I believe twilio is the solution however I couldn't find any source code on this topic in their website. Has anyone done this task successfully? (If twilio isn't the best solution I am open for other suggestions)

Comment: Did you checked their official docs: [Authy One-Time Passwords (OTP)](https://www.twilio.com/docs/authy/api/one-time-passwords), [Account Verification with Authy, Node.js and Express](https://www.twilio.com/docs/authy/tutorials/account-verification-node-express#linkcode) ?

Comment: yes however there is nothing about react native.